# How to invoke a command button present in sheet 1 of book1 using VBA code from book2 module1

Tags: excel, vba

I have a command button present in Sheet1 of book1 with name 'extract data' and the code is as mentioned below

```
Private Sub ButtonExtractData_Click()
'code 
End Sub
```

I have written the below code and it gives me error:

> *Cannot run the macro 'Book1.sheet1.ButtonExtractData_Click' macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.*

```
Sub run_macro()
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\folder1\book1.xlsm"
    Application.Run "book1.xlsm!Control.Sheet1.ButtonExtractData_Click"
End Sub
```

How can I trigger this button click from another workbook?

Comment: just `ButtonExtractData_Click` I think

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be invoking `Click` handlers. Not from another workbook, not from the workbook it's implemented in, not from anywhere. Event handlers are invoked when *events* are fired by whatever object raises an event: they're `Private` for a reason - no other code should *ever* invoke them directly.

You wouldn't do it in Java, you wouldn't do it in C#, don't do it in VBA.

---

The handler is in a worksheet's code-behind; it's not a macro, it's an implementation detail that actually lives at *instance* level, for a worksheet module is a special kind of *class module*, and `Sheet1` is actually an *object* - and `Application.Run` doesn't work with *objects*, it works with *macros*.

Take whatever code is in the body of that event handler, move it to a parameterless `Public Sub` in a separate "standard module" (.bas), and then make your click handler invoke *that* procedure.

*Now* you have a macro. Let's say you called it `DoSomething`. You can invoke it like this:

```
Application.Run "'book1.xlsm'!DoSomething"
```

Comment: Great! See [how does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/197901) if you're not sure what to do next ;-)